# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a "-js-expanded" class to this element if someone hover over a tag. how can I do this?

```html
<a href="" target="_self" class="sticky-cta" onmouseover="myFunction()" >
  <span class="sticky-label">GET STARTED</span>
  <i class="icon-features-productivity"></i>
</a>
```

```js
  function myFunction () {
      this.classList.toggle("-js-expanded");
  }
```

```css
  .-js-expanded {
  color: red;
  }
```

Comment: `this` in your code doesn't refer to an element. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the inline listeners.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function myFunction (element) {
      element.classList.toggle("-js-expanded");
  }
```

```css
.-js-expanded {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<a href="" target="_self" class="sticky-cta" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" >
  <span class="sticky-label">GET STARTED</span>
  <i class="icon-features-productivity"></i>
</a>
```